# Neutralize Poison and previous poison ability damage

Tags: dnd-3.5e

If a creature gets poisoned and loses 1d3 Str and will lose another 1d3 after a minute but someone casts [Neutralize Poison](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/neutralizePoison.htm) on it, does it regain the first 1d3 lost too as well as not rolling for the second 1d3?
What kind of temporary effects does it cure? Nausea and the like? How about unconsciousness or sleep?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**, the Str already lost remains lost until regained naturally or with magic.

That is directly supported by the [spell description](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/neutralizePoison.htm) (emphasis mine):

> the spell does not reverse instantaneous effects, such as hit point damage, **temporary ability damage**, or effects that don’t go away on their own.

Any condition effect (like nausea or unconsciousness) will be ended by the spell. Furthermore, if the secondary effect had not yet occured, it will not occur.

> A poisoned creature suffers no additional effects from the poison.

Comment: @Simanos In the group I play with, we call those "Accidental Liberties" and try to not break the rules once we know them. :-)